# Use AVPlayer to Skip Forward/Backward X seconds in Live Broadcast?

Tags: swift, avplayer, http-live-streaming

Using this live broadcast (https://stream.radioparadise.com/mp3-320) I’d like to allow X seconds forward and backward skipping using AVPlayer. But using the seek function in AVPlayer the skipping doesn’t seem to be working properly. Does anybody know if it’s possible to include this functionality in Swift using a live broadcast? Or does the functionality have to exist at the stream level? The backward skip feature is implemented as

```
 self.player?.seek(to: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(CMTimeGetSeconds((self.player?.currentTime())!).advanced(by: -30), preferredTimescale: 1))
```

However, when I print out the AVPlayer item's see

```
Seekable Time Range:  Optional([CMTimeRange: {{0/1000 = 0.000}, {0/1000 = 0.000}}])
Loaded Time Range: Optional([CMTimeRange: {{0/1 = 0.000}, {661504/22050 = 30.000}}])
Current Time:  2.142512821
```

Is there any way to download the stream and play it in pieces? Or some alternative?

Thanks